# Upload a file before form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form to apply for a job.In which the user should be allowed to upload a resume,also the form have a dropdown that allow the user to select from the list of previously uploaded resume.Now to my question,I need the new resume to be uploaded without form submission and repopulate the dropdown with the newly uploaded resume.So the user now can apply the job by selecting the resumes listed in dropdown.Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Json** in order to prevent full postback in your page. After that you must return to Partial View.

As instance;

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName"/>
<input type="button" onclick="ButonClick()" value="Enter"/>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function ButonClick() {
    var data= {
         UserName: $('#UserName').val(),
     };

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/MyActionResult",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult(string UserName , MyModel model)
{
    var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("_YourPartialView", model);
    return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Note:**

You need below code to render your partial view for json.

Add below to your controller too.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
       var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
       var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData,   TempData, sw);
       viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
       viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
       return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
     }
}
```

Comment: He uses only MVC not ASP pages